# Connecting to DSN created by SQLite driver

Tags: sqlite, sqlanywhere

How to connect to DSN created by SQlite Driver using SQL anywhere APIs from C++ code?
I am using db_string_connect() to connect to sybase adaptive server anywhere. I want to use the same function to connect to the DSN created by SQLite Driver as well but db_string_connect() API is returning sqlcode -103 ["You supplied an invalid user ID or an incorrect password."].
I have this somewhat weird requirement because I want to abstract the connection to different databases at ODBC layer. And the code to connect to sybase is already written and I want to minimize the changes in the code. Hope I am making some sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use a function from SQL Anywhere client library to connect directly to some other database. Typically, if you need to be able to connect and manipulate different types of database systems, you have to introduce a database layer that sits between the vendor specific client libraries and your code. This could be something you write yourself or use an existing one.